# A Query Copy from 1 table into another + Values

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to make this query work but i keep getting error.

```
insert into Table1 (CL1,CL2) Values ('TEST',CL2)
SELECT CL2 from Table2 where ID = 2
```

I am trying to take data from table 2 and put it in table 2 with the name TEST

Table1 
is Empty

Table2
ID=2,SUP,SUP,SUP

if any one can help it would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into Table1 (CL1,CL2) SELECT 'TEST', CL2 from Table2 where ID = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (CL1,CL2) VALUES ('TEST',(SELECT CL2 FROM Table2 WHERE ID=2))
```